# Cache exception in symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, exception, caching

When I excute my code many time I get

> server error 500 in the console

and no data has charged when I check the error I get cache error and then I have to refresh the page to get data. I don't know why I get this exception!!!

can someone help me and tell me how can I avoid this exception in symfony :

```
class: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException"
message: "Warning: rename(C:\wamp\www\myproject\app\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__DefaultAppBundleEntityService.php.568513d40be3a3.02053948,C:\wamp\www\myproject\app\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__DefaultAppBundleEntityService.php): "
```

**Help!**

unfortunatly I can't resolve this problem can someone help me please ????!!!

- Sometimes all queries run without problem or errors but if I refresh the page it may that I get this error for one or more requests

Comment: Is this really the exact path name? The reason I am asking is that recently there have been some bugs in Symfony and Doctrine Cache with long path names on Windows (but the length of the paths in your error message is too short).

Comment: Yes @xabbuh it s the exact path name

Comment: @xabbuh can you tell me how did you resolve this bug please ?

Comment: Sorry, except for the long path I have no idea what could cause this issue. Can you run the affected command with `-vvv` to see if you can get a full stack trace for this error?

Comment: Ok thank you @xabbuh .. which command?(I get this error when I refresh a page or when I go to an other one from the menu)

Comment: I thought you were running a command because you wrote "server error 500 in the console".

Comment: I mean navigator console

Answer (score 0):

Please check the user and owner of the file. assign them the same user and owner which are running php apache on your system. This worked for me.